# Typescript: How to define only one type of javascript object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose that i have an object like:

```
const obj = [
  { createdAt: "2022-10-25T08:06:29.392Z", updatedAt: "2022-10-25T08:06:29.392Z"},
  { createdAt: "2022-10-25T08:06:29.392Z", animal: "cat"}
]
```

I want to create a function to order by createdAt, which is the only field i'm sure it will be in the object.
The function will be something like:

```
export const sortArrayByCreatedAt = (arr: TypeArr) => {
    return arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return new Date(b.createdAt).valueOf() - new Date(a.createdAt).valueOf();
    });
};
```

How can i define the type of arr?

```
Type TypeArr {
  createdAt: string
}
```

Is it good practice to define the type of the only known var?

I think that if someone else will see this function he will think that obj contains only createdAt, but i didn't find a better solution.

Comment: If you have 2 possible interfaces, you could define the parameter as `Array<A | B>`. If both of these interfaces have the `createdAt` property, your code should compile just fine.

Comment: `interface TypeArr { createdAt: string; updatedAt?: string; animal?: string}` and `const obj: TypeArr[] = [...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define my `TypeArr` as an interface and the sort method as a generic method. So it wouldn't change the return type.

```
export const sortArrayByCreatedAt = <T extends TypeArr>(arr: Array<T>) => {
    return arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return new Date(b.createdAt).valueOf() - new Date(a.createdAt).valueOf();
    });
};

interface TypeArr{
    createdAt :string
}

const obj = [
  { createdAt: "2022-10-25T08:06:29.392Z", updatedAt: "2022-10-25T08:06:29.392Z"},
  { createdAt: "2022-10-25T08:06:29.392Z", animal: "cat"}
]

const sorted = sortArrayByCreatedAt(obj);
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WGAb9N)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are also returning the array which you pass to the function. Right now, the return type would only be `TypeArr[]` which does not reflect the additional properties in the objects.

I would make `sortArrayByCreatedAt` generic.

```
export const sortArrayByCreatedAt = <T extends { createdAt: string }[]>(arr: T): T => {
    return arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return new Date(b.createdAt).valueOf() - new Date(a.createdAt).valueOf();
    });
};
```

The input type will also be the return type now.

Answer (score 0):

You can have optional properties in types or interfaces using a question mark `?`:

```js
type MyType = {
    createdAt: string;
    updatedAt?: string;
    animal?: string;
}
```

```js
interface MyInterface {
    createdAt: string;
    updatedAt?: string;
    animal?: string;
}
```

If you are typing an array of the object, you would use `MyType[]` or `MyInterface[]` e.g.

```js
export const sortArrayByCreatedAt = (arr: MyType[]) => {
    return arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return new Date(b.createdAt).valueOf() - new Date(a.createdAt).valueOf();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an interface and use the question mark `?` in front of optional properties:

```
interface TypeArr {
  createdAt: string
  updatedAt?: string
  animal?: string
}
```